# Как называется, когда функция написана вверху

Tags: c++

Короче, забыл как называется, когда есть вот такая запись:

```
void a(int);//вот, когда так пишут функцию вверху, как такая запись называется?
int main(){
    int b = 24;
    a(b);
}
void a(int c){
    cout<<c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прототип/Объявление функции.

Ссылки:

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объявление_(информатика)#Объявления_функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прототип_функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/3.1.php

Comment: От души, большое спасибо!